# Sticky banner not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a sticky banner on my webpage, but I've encountered some problems. I think I know what the problem is, but I don't have a clue how to solve it.

This is the JQuery coding for the sticky banner:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if( $(this).scrollTop() > 175 ) {
    nav ul.addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
}   
else { 
    nav ul.removeClass("main-nav-scrolled");
}
});
```

And this is the CSS coding that my navigation menu uses:

```
  .nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #10bbb6;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #088783;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #088783;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
}

  .nav li {
    width: 110px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
```

I'm totally new to the JQuery concept, and I've done a lot of research, but nothing that could solve my problem.
I think that in je Jquery coding the "nav ul" isnt recognized.

```
nav ul.addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
```

I've also tried

```
nav.addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
```

But that didn't work either.

Other important CSS tags are:

```
 .main-nav-scrolled {position: fixed;
    top:0;}
    #top { position: fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%
    }

#bottom {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #10bbb6;  
    overflow: scroll;
}

#bottom,
#top { position: relative; }
```

And this is how it's placed in the body:

```
    <body class="news">

<div id="top">
<a href="Homepage.html"><IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:10px; LEFT:125px; WIDTH:150px; HEIGHT:150px" SRC="afbeeldingen/kledingbank2.jpg"></a> 

<div class="banner"> Kledingbank Zaltbommel, voor iedereen. </div>
</div>

  <header>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="Home"><a href="Homepage.html">Homepage</a></li>
        <li class="Home"><a href="Over ons.html">Over ons</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a href="Sponsoren.html">Sponsoren</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="Kleding.html">Kleding</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="Vacaturen.html">Vacaturen</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a class="active" href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="bottom">
 <BR>

 <div class="link">
<center><p> Er is nog steeds veel vraag naar vrijwilligers! Heeft u interesse in het zijn van vrijwilliger bij de kledingbank, aarzel dan niet.
Stuur een mail naar <a href="mailto:KledingbankZaltbommel@gmail.com"> Kledingbank Zaltbommel</a> en wij nemen verder contact met u op! </center></p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Change the nav ul.addClass to $("ul.nav").addClass, and of course also change it for the remove class

Comment: give an ID to your nav then you can call like $("#ID ul").addClass("");

Comment: Anoop LL that's what I think the problem is. How do I give a ID to the nav in css?

Comment: @G.Man - before we can continue to help, it would really help if you posted the markup to your navigation menu.  And the CSS to main-nav-scrolled.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky would this be enough?

Comment: @G.Man can we please see the HTML markup to your menu as well?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky I don't understand what you'd like to see. I'm sorry for my small knowledge of coding in english. But haven't I given html coding for the menu already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, your jQuery had no element defined as a reference in the first place. Thus, `nav ul.addClass()` did nothing because there was no jQuery object created to match that reference.

Further looking at your markup, I would reference the `header` element to add your sticky class instead of the unordered list, since `header` is the parent of the menu.

As such, you would have this script (preferably before the closing `</body>` tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var nav = $('header');

   if( $(this).scrollTop() > 175 ) {
    nav.addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
   }   
   else { 
     nav.removeClass("main-nav-scrolled");
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried changing it, but this didn't work. The sticky banner stil doesn't work.

Comment: Is the class being added to the `header` using my script above? Try viewing the page with an element inspector to verify

Comment: It doesn't look like the class is being added to the header.

Comment: I got your code to work in a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvLtfe8e/
**Note: I added a bunch of padding to your `#bottom` container so you could get enough scroll that the script adds the sticky class

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Even though the sticky banner DOES work on JSFiddle, it somehow doesn't work when I paste it in my Notepad++ coding.

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the jQuery library properly. Right before the closing `</head>` tag, include your script reference for jQuery (I like to use cdnjs.com):
`<!-- All your head stuff -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>`

Comment: I've provided a JSFiddle page with basically my whole page. Maybe you can figure out why it isn't working here: https://jsfiddle.net/yr2nagha/

Comment: JSFiddle is kinda different in how it adds some tags for you, so to make it more clear, I wrote it all up in a plain-text file called `sticky-test.html`. You can download it, then view it in Notepad++ to see what I did: http://www.filedropper.com/sticky-test

Comment: Thank you for you help, I'll have to edit the layout a bit but this solved my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the item in Jquery first so:

This

```
nav ul.addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
```

should be this

```
$(".nav ul").addClass("main-nav-scrolled");
```

Comment: would there be any difference in writing it: $("ul.nav")??  That's where my brain went first- just want to be sure there's nothing I'm missing.

Comment: I changed it, but my sticky banner still doesn't work. The banner simply doesn't stick to the top of the page.

Comment: Based on your CSS, you have a `ul` as a child of  `.nav` so `$("ul.nav")` would not be correct.

Comment: You need to provide a demo then.

Comment: @G.Man - please provide the HTML and also the CSS to main-nav-scrolled